# function generator optimize JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, generator

I have an api which spits out a plain object, and also I have a generator, by which I get a number of items from that object. Here's a minimized code:

```js
const apiData = [
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 },
  { a: 4 },
  { a: 5 },
  { a: 6 },
  { a: 7 }
];

function* gen(num = 1) {
  let data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < apiData.length; i++) {

    data.push(apiData[i])

    if (data.length == num) {
      num = yield data;
      data = [];
    }
  }
  return data
}


let nextData = gen(3);
console.log(nextData.next())
console.log(nextData.next(2))
console.log(nextData.next(4))
```

As you can see everything works perfect and fine, but I think if I could change the final lines to something like the following would be more readable:

```
let nextData = gen();
console.log(nextData.next(3))
console.log(nextData.next(2))
console.log(nextData.next(4))
```

but its not working as it should. 
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You are right, i meant javascript object

Comment: Why do you even use generator for this ?

Comment: that's an example i showed here, the main code and data is much complex, and I need to get a chunk of data each time and perform some actions on it.